# Проблема при выводе данных из MySQL таблицы, используя переменную _REQUEST + ЧПУ

Tags: php, mysql, чпу

Есть таблица "heroes" в MySQL
[image: таблица]

Если я делаю выборку по полю `id`, используя переменную `$_GET`, то все получается.
Но если я использую следующий код

```
    mysql_connect("localhost", "sample", "sample") or die (mysql_error ());
    mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM heroes WHERE url=" . $_REQUEST[url];
    $result = mysql_query($strSQL);
    mysql_close();

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result); //Line #13
```

То я получаю следующую ошибку
[image: ошибка]
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?
И что необходимо сделать, чтобы урл страницы вместо `article.php?url=abbadon` был `article/abbadon`?

Comment: Какой запрос подаёться в mysql_query, и mysql_error получи с помощью этой функции ошибку, это пото му что запрос сформировался не правильно.

Comment: Если честно, То не понял ничего :/

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понимаю, то у вас запрос вообще не должен выполниться.

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM heroes WHERE url=" . $_REQUEST[url];
```

У вас `url` - это строка, надо в кавычки брать:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM heroes WHERE url='" . $_REQUEST["hero-url"]."'";
```

Comment: Ошибка больше не выводится, спасибо. Но похоже, что данные не записываются в переменную $row

Comment: @n000000b там пусто просто. В `$_REQUEST[url]` у вас будет вроде как **article.php?url=abbadon**, по такой строке в базе просто ничего нет.

Comment: Если прочитать содержимое    `$_REQUEST` при помощи     `<? print_r ($_REQUEST) ; ?>` то выведется следующее `Array ( [hero-url] => abbadon )`

Comment: @n000000b вы сами ответили на свой вопрос. Вы выводите `$_REQUEST[url]` когда у вас записано `hero-url`. Попробуйте написать  `$_REQUEST[hero-url]` в запросе

Comment: @Moonvvell точно, cпасибо! А как быть со второй частью вопроса (про ЧПУ) не подскажите? :) Я гуглил, но ничего дельного не получилось

Comment: @n000000b смотреть в сторону RewriteCond/RewriteRule. Я к сожаление в этом не очень знаюсь. Но тут за сегодня было уже пару тем о них, полистайте сайт.

Comment: @n000000b если апач, то htaccess мучать. Если nginx, то его конфиг.